# Django: Method to get url of images

Tags: python, django

Im working on an website currently i would like to switch from a class Product containing the images to following:

models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name    = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    price   = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    
    # Digital Products do not need shipping
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=False)
    # now being handled in ProductImage:
    # image   = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.image.url
        # get placeholder if something does not work
        except: 
            url = '/images/placeholder.png'
        return url
    

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    
    product     = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name="images", on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=None, null=True)
    image1      = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    image2      = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    image3      = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    image4      = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    image5      = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    image6      = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
```

i used to get the url of the single image (which works fine if image is an attribute of Product) as follows:

view.html:

```
{% for product in products %}    
    <img class="thumbnail" src="{{ product.imageURL }}">
{% endfor %}
```

view.py:

```
def store_view(request):
    # some code
    "product":Product.objects.all()
    context.update({"products":products})
    return render(request, "view.html", context)
```

##### Is there a way of getting the images through the ForeignKey relation? (For example by modification of the above method imageURL)?

I have tried:

models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model)
    # same as above
    
    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.images.image1.url
        # get placeholder if something does not work
        except:
            url = '/images/placeholder.png'
        return url
```

but this raises an AttributeError: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'image1'.
Other possible solutions are appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is like that because `self.images` returns set of `ProductImage` objects. Even it is only one, you will have `QuerySet` object with one `ProductImage` object, like:

```
<QuerySet [<ProductImage object (1)>]>
```

You can change relation to `OneToOneField` if you don't plan to have more related `ProductImage` objects to `Product`. Then you can relate simply like you have tried:

```
class ProductImage(models.Model):
    
    product     = models.OneToOneField(Product, related_name="images", on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=None, null=True)
    image1      = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    ...
```

Comment: That worked! However, lets say i would need to stay at a ForeignKey relation, what options do i have then?

Comment: Then you have to say which object from `QuerySet` you want to get. If you are sure there will be always one, then you can change `self.images.image1.url` to `self.images.first().image1.url`. But it will not be good practise, if there always is one :)

Answer (score -1):

in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

...

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?